# Throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Baskmali

Tags: smali

I'm getting the following exception when trying to run baksmali on Android O services.odex

```
Error occurred while loading class path files. Aborting.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1701056665
    at org.jf.dexlib2.dexbacked.BaseDexBuffer.readSmallUint(BaseDexBuffer.java:53)
    at org.jf.dexlib2.dexbacked.DexBackedClassDef.<init>(DexBackedClassDef.java:78)
    at org.jf.dexlib2.dexbacked.DexBackedDexFile$1.readItem(DexBackedDexFile.java:137)
    at org.jf.dexlib2.dexbacked.DexBackedDexFile$1.readItem(DexBackedDexFile.java:133)
    at org.jf.dexlib2.dexbacked.util.FixedSizeSet$1.next(FixedSizeSet.java:56)
    at org.jf.dexlib2.analysis.DexClassProvider.<init>(DexClassProvider.java:48)
    at org.jf.dexlib2.analysis.ClassPathResolver.<init>(ClassPathResolver.java:163)
    at org.jf.dexlib2.analysis.ClassPathResolver.<init>(ClassPathResolver.java:85)
    at org.jf.baksmali.AnalysisArguments.loadClassPathForDexFile(AnalysisArguments.java:135)
    at org.jf.baksmali.AnalysisArguments.loadClassPathForDexFile(AnalysisArguments.java:86)
    at org.jf.baksmali.DisassembleCommand.getOptions(DisassembleCommand.java:207)
    at org.jf.baksmali.DeodexCommand.getOptions(DeodexCommand.java:71)
    at org.jf.baksmali.DisassembleCommand.run(DisassembleCommand.java:181)
    at org.jf.baksmali.Main.main(Main.java:102)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the latest version (2.2.2). Then try

```
 adb pull /system/framework /tmp/framework
baksmali x -d /tmp/framework/arm64 /tmp/framework/oat/arm64/services.odex
```